# How does Tensroflow initialize kernel weights in LSTM / GRU cells?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Reading Tensorflow rnn cells [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py) I've came across the following `GRUCell` code:

```
self._gate_kernel = self.add_variable(
    "gates/%s" % _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME,
    shape=[input_depth + self._num_units, 2 * self._num_units],
    initializer=self._kernel_initializer)
self._gate_bias = self.add_variable(
    "gates/%s" % _BIAS_VARIABLE_NAME,
    shape=[2 * self._num_units],
    initializer=(
        self._bias_initializer
        if self._bias_initializer is not None
        else init_ops.constant_initializer(1.0, dtype=self.dtype)))
self._candidate_kernel = self.add_variable(
    "candidate/%s" % _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME,
    shape=[input_depth + self._num_units, self._num_units],
    initializer=self._kernel_initializer)
self._candidate_bias = self.add_variable(
    "candidate/%s" % _BIAS_VARIABLE_NAME,
    shape=[self._num_units],
    initializer=(
        self._bias_initializer
        if self._bias_initializer is not None
        else init_ops.zeros_initializer(dtype=self.dtype)))
```

You can see that gate bias tensor is initialized with `1` and candidate bias with `0` while gate kernel and candidate kernel tensors do not have default initializers (`self._kernel_initializer=None`) if we don't explicitly provide them. So does Tensorflow populate these tensors with random numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add_variable` method here ends up calling `add_weight` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4ca24c6e7df49881ae5770c331a29778a43d3c4c/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L490).

As you can see if no initializer is specified and dtype is a floating point number, `initializers.glorot_uniform()` is used.